# Timeout error while query execution in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am getting TimeOut error in Entity Framework while executing queries.

I have an API which has like 10 request per second and 10-12 database methods are getting called inside that so I am getting timeout error.

I have looked and found that default timeout is 30 second so I have increased the timeout to 5 minutes but now some processes are stop getting pool and I have started getting errors:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached..

So how can I manage this scenario? How can I play between execution timeout and pool?

Comment: Are these queries you are writing or the ones automatically created? It sounds like perhaps your connections are not being handled properly. But with nothing more than a description it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: I got a feeling that you don't have proper index on the table and your linq query can be heavily optimized. This might result in 100% disk usage.

Comment: I am using code first approach of entityframework so using the methods of entity framework to get the data and insert data.\

Comment: @Steve : I have put the indexing on the table as well

Comment: Then it is very likely that @Steve is correct. Need to get some proper indexing in place. You saying that you have put the indexing on the table is not really indicative that it is good indexing. Share the table definiton (including indexes) and the queries you are running. Getting an execution would be a big plus.

Comment: @NiteshKumar is the index being used? have you used sql sniffer to see the query sent by linq and analysis the query plan?

Comment: Increasing the timeout is usually not the best approach.  What @Steve said about indexes is the best way to go.   Based on the pool error, I'm guessing that you are not disposing of your connections and commands properly, but without seeing code it is just a guess.

Comment: @Chris Yes I am not disposing the connection currently. Will do it Now.

Comment: @Steve I didnot use sql sniffer , will give a try to use the same as well

Comment: @Steve how many Non-cluster index should i make on my table.

Comment: @NiteshKumar one less is too little, one extra is too much. index = slower write for faster read. The trade off is unavoidable. Welcome to the Sql world.

Comment: @NiteshKumar - Depends on your indexing needs. Look at how your queries expect the data to be returned. For example, if a query is looking for all invoices for a given customer in the last year, you absolutely need an index by customer ID, but you may also want that index to include the invoice date field. If you want all invoices from the last three months, you need an additional index by invoice date. Your requirements, and trade offs between select speed and insert/update speed define the indexes you need.